# writing proc avg in tcl script in NS2

Tags: tcl, proc, ns2

I want to calculate avg of { energy_level ,number of nodes & traffic's data on nodes } by one mobile sink in the network with 5 static nodes.
 I have to calculate this avg with proc in tcl script code not with awk code.

Please help me

Comment: What have you tried? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have collected a list of values that you want to compute the average of, use this procedure to do the computation:

```
proc ArithmeticMean {listOfValues} {
    set length [llength $listOfValues]
    if {$length == 0} {
        return 0.0
    }
    set sum [::tcl::mathop::+ {*}$listOfValues]
    return [expr {double($sum) / $length}]
}
```

The summing of the values uses the `+` “operator command” with expansion syntax, and is the cheapest way of adding them all together.